# cannot run sos comamnd for Silverlight 4.0 app in IE 8.0

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-8, windbg, sos

I am trying to debug my silverlight application running under IE8.0. Its using .NET framework 4.0 and Silverlight 4.0. So I attach Windbg to IE running instance, I understand that with IE8 I need to connect to right instance of internet explorer. So when I attach here are the dlls that been shown as loaded in the process. As you can see the coreclr is loaded in there.

> Executable search path is: 
>   ModLoad: 00a00000 00a9c000   C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE
>   ModLoad: 77890000 779b8000   C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
>   ModLoad: 76450000 7652c000   C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
>   ModLoad: 76380000 76446000   C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
>   ModLoad: 779d0000 77a93000   C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
>   ModLoad: 76680000 7671d000   C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
>   ModLoad: 77aa0000 77aeb000   C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
>   ModLoad: 77590000 7763a000   C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
>   ModLoad: 77530000 77589000   C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
>   ModLoad: 76940000 77451000   C:\Windows\system32\SHELL32.dll
>   ModLoad: 76530000 76675000   C:\Windows\system32\ole32.dll
>   ModLoad: 75f60000 76149000   C:\Windows\system32\iertutil.dll
>   ModLoad: 77750000 77883000   C:\Windows\system32\urlmon.dll
>   ModLoad: 768b0000 7693d000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
>   ModLoad: 77730000 7774e000   C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
>   ModLoad: 77460000 77528000   C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
>   ModLoad: 76330000 76339000   C:\Windows\system32\LPK.DLL
>   ModLoad: 6be40000 6c8d5000   C:\Windows\system32\IEFRAME.dll
>   ModLoad: 76220000 76293000   C:\Windows\system32\comdlg32.dll
>   ModLoad: 72570000 725a3000   C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEShims.dll
>   ModLoad: 74f60000 74f9f000   C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
>   ModLoad: 75de0000 75dfe000   C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
>   ModLoad: 75dc0000 75dd4000   C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll
>   ModLoad: 75430000 7546b000   C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
>   ModLoad: 76720000 768aa000   C:\Windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
>   ModLoad: 73e40000 73efb000   C:\Windows\system32\PROPSYS.dll
>   ModLoad: 762a0000 76324000   C:\Windows\system32\CLBCatQ.DLL
>   ModLoad: 722c0000 72300000   C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll
>   ModLoad: 6eae0000 6eb33000   C:\Windows\system32\ACTXPRXY.DLL
>   ModLoad: 77640000 77726000   C:\Windows\system32\WININET.dll
>   ModLoad: 76370000 76373000   C:\Windows\system32\Normaliz.dll
>   ModLoad: 76340000 7636d000   C:\Windows\system32\ws2_32.dll
>   ModLoad: 779c0000 779c6000   C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
>   ModLoad: 75d30000 75d5c000   C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
>   ModLoad: 74460000 744aa000   C:\Windows\system32\RASAPI32.dll
>   ModLoad: 74440000 74454000   C:\Windows\system32\rasman.dll
>   ModLoad: 75bf0000 75c66000   C:\Windows\system32\NETAPI32.dll
>   ModLoad: 75e90000 75e97000   C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
>   ModLoad: 74170000 741a1000   C:\Windows\system32\TAPI32.dll
>   ModLoad: 74430000 7443c000   C:\Windows\system32\rtutils.dll
>   ModLoad: 74130000 74162000   C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
>   ModLoad: 740f0000 7412d000   C:\Windows\system32\OLEACC.dll
>   ModLoad: 75830000 75922000   C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
>   ModLoad: 75990000 759a2000   C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
>   ModLoad: 6ffe0000 6ffe6000   C:\Windows\system32\sensapi.dll
>   ModLoad: 755f0000 755f7000   C:\Windows\system32\credssp.dll
>   ModLoad: 754c0000 75506000   C:\Windows\system32\schannel.dll
>   ModLoad: 75120000 75134000   C:\Windows\system32\wpclsp.dll
>   ModLoad: 759b0000 759c1000   C:\Windows\system32\SAMLIB.dll
>   ModLoad: 75200000 7520f000   C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
>   ModLoad: 75790000 757a9000   C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
>   ModLoad: 75750000 75785000   C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
>   ModLoad: 759d0000 759fc000   C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
>   ModLoad: 75740000 75747000   C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
>   ModLoad: 75710000 75732000   C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
>   ModLoad: 755b0000 755eb000   C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
>   ModLoad: 754b0000 754b5000   C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
>   ModLoad: 709e0000 709e6000   C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
>   ModLoad: 70a40000 70a70000   C:\Windows\system32\MLANG.dll
>   ModLoad: 75230000 75251000   C:\Windows\system32\NTMARTA.DLL
>   ModLoad: 76150000 76199000   C:\Windows\system32\WLDAP32.dll
>   ModLoad: 756a0000 756a8000   C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
>   ModLoad: 75690000 75695000   C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
>   ModLoad: 704d0000 704df000   C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
>   ModLoad: 70490000 704a2000   C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
>   ModLoad: 704c0000 704c8000   C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
>   ModLoad: 704b0000 704bc000   C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
>   ModLoad: 75290000 752a5000   C:\Windows\system32\GPAPI.dll
>   ModLoad: 757f0000 7582a000   C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
>   ModLoad: 6ffc0000 6ffdb000   C:\Windows\system32\cryptnet.dll
>   ModLoad: 74ef0000 74f05000   C:\Windows\system32\Cabinet.dll
>   ModLoad: 56070000 563d9000   c:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\coreclr.dll

Here is the output of chain command

> 0:027> .chain
>   Extension DLL search Path:
>       C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\WINXP;C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext;C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext\arcade;C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\pri;C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86);C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext\arcade;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared
>   Extension DLL chain:
>       C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll: image 4.0.30319.225, API 1.0.0, built Wed Feb 09 23:49:57 2011
>           [path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll]
>       C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll: image 4.0.30319.225, built Wed Feb 09 23:24:43 2011
>           [path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll]
>       C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\coreclr: image 4.0.60129.0, built Sat Jan 29 02:06:01 2011
>           [path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\coreclr.dll]
>       C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\sos.dll: image 4.0.60129.0, API 1.0.0, built Sat Jan 29 02:07:57 2011
>           [path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\sos.dll]
>       C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\sos: image 4.0.60129.0, API 1.0.0, built Sat Jan 29 02:07:57 2011
>           [path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\sos.dll]
>       C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\sos: image 2.0.50727.4211, API 1.0.0, built Mon Oct 25 01:31:50 2010
>           [path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\sos.dll]
>       dbghelp: image 6.12.0002.633, API 6.1.6, built Mon Feb 01 15:08:26 2010
>           [path: C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\dbghelp.dll]
>       ext: image 6.12.0002.633, API 1.0.0, built Mon Feb 01 15:08:31 2010
>           [path: C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext\ext.dll]
>       exts: image 6.12.0002.633, API 1.0.0, built Mon Feb 01 15:08:24 2010
>           [path: C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\WINXP\exts.dll]
>       uext: image 6.12.0002.633, API 1.0.0, built Mon Feb 01 15:08:23 2010
>           [path: C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\winext\uext.dll]
>       ntsdexts: image 6.1.7650.0, API 1.0.0, built Mon Feb 01 15:08:08 2010
>           [path: C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]

Problem is that after loading sos when I try to load sos, I get following error.

> 0:027> .loadby sos coreclr
>   0:027> !threads
>   Failed to find runtime DLL (clr.dll), 0x80004005
>   Extension commands need clr.dll in order to have something to do.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason is .net framework 4.0 sos is loaded. You would have unload .net framework sos using `.unload` command. You could see the .net framework sos loaded in `.chain` output.

Answer (score 0):

I think Naveen is right. Check your chain result, you'll see

[path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\sos.dll]

and then further down

[path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\4.0.60129.0\sos.dll]